# How to enforce data validation in Excel on a function executing a macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm compiling a database of companies and corresponding 3-letter acronyms. I have this macro that automatically generates an acronym when a new company is added to the database.

```
Function Abbv(pWorkRng As Range) As String
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim xValue As String
    Dim output As String

    xValue = pWorkRng.Value
    arr = VBA.Split(Trim(xValue))

    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        output = output & VBA.Left(arr(i), 1) & ""
    Next

    output = Left(output, 3)
    Abbv = output
End Function
```

I'm trying to enforce a data validation against inputting a duplicate entry so that any newly generated acronyms aren't the same as any previously existing acronyms (on the off chance that the initials of a newly added company are the same as an acronym already in the database).

This is the formula I have for preventing duplicate entries but it still allows auto-generated acronyms to be a duplicate.

```
=COUNTIF($D$1:$D$200,D1)=1
```

How do I get this duplicate entry warning to prevent any auto-generated acronyms from being duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [WorksheetFunction.CountIf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839272.aspx) method

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Arg1, Arg2)
```

Where …

- `Arg1` is the range of cells from which you want to count cells like `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$D$1:$D$200")` and
- `Arg` is the criteria in the form of a number, expression, cell reference, or text that defines which cells will be counted: e.g. your `Abbv`.

Comment: So I put that into the data validation formula, and I still have the same problem. Anything I manually type in triggers the duplicate entry warning, and any auto-generated acronym that shares the name of a previously existing one is allowed

Comment: @A.Shetty No it wasn't meant for Excel's data validation, it was meant to use the code above in your Abbv generation function to check if the newly generated Abbv is already existing or not to then give an error message or do something else.